# How to fix reversed parentheses?

Tags: sas

I'm having a problem with an input field written backwards.
There is no problem using the reverse() function for that matter.
The problem occurs when values in field includes parentheses...

Here are few examples of inputs, after I reverted them
(The input is not written in english but it isn't relevant i guess).

```
    )CAR( ABCDEF
    AAAA MOTORCYCLE(
    AAA 456 ) DDD(
```

I'm sure there is a way to fix this.
I thought using substr() and find().
when the open parenthes position is greater than the close one,
but as you can see, there are examples of values include just the open parenthes
or just the close one.

Need your help please :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use translate in a data step.

```
good_string = translate(bad_string,'(',')' , ')','(')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, Shorack! It actually fixed most of my problems, but I still have a problem in cases of 2 open parenth, or 2 close parenth... what can be done with such cases? Thanks again, Gal.